# why does my 'style.css' file become 'style.css?ver=4.1.1'?

Tags: wordpress

I am using wordpress and I've made a theme child folder with style.css in it.

I've done a little work to it and saved it, but the problem is, only that first save of style.css is being activated.  I've added more code into style.css but my new code is not being applied.

In the inspect element, it's loading up "style.css?ver=4.1.1" and not "style.css".  How can I make it load my newest style.css, not the cached one?

Thank you!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

?ver=4.1.1 is adding to it beacuse that is defined as the stylesheet version in your funtions.php when enqueuing the css file. if you look through your funtions.php you should be able to find something like

```
 wp_register_style("main-styles", get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . "/style.css", '', '4.1.1');
```

or

```
wp_enqueue_style("main-styles", get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . "/style.css", '', '4.1.1');
```

and that last part is responsible for adding that when u inspect element. If you need to see the site without cache version just hit ctrl+f5 and it will load the site with new changes.

Answer (score 0):

In my case the hosting provider was using Max CDN and then deprecated it and the site was still using it with no option to disable it from the hosting control panel ant longer so I had to contact their support and they were able to disable it for me